# How to calculate the IOU Score from WKT Polygons?

Tags: python, pytorch, confusion-matrix

How can i calculate the IOU Score for full Tile having Multiple Buildings.And how can i calculate the IOU Score for all of the images in my test data.
[Prediction File](https://www49.zippyshare.com/v/GzFal9oH/file.html)
[Groun Truths File](https://www49.zippyshare.com/v/5tGQwBZT/file.html)
Is there any way to calculate the IOU Score from these files.Please Help.I have tried to reprsent the both(Ground Truths and Predictions) in QGIS photo attached.
I have wrtten the code to calculate the IOU Score. Now i want to make sure that, my method is reliable or not?
Code is given Below

```html
import pandas as pd
import csv
import shapely
import shapely.wkt as wkt
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon
import shapely.ops as so
import shapely.geometry as sg
import shapely.ops as so
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def polt_image(mul_poly_shape):
    if isinstance(mul_poly_shape, list):
        image_plot = MultiPolygon(map(wkt.loads, mul_poly_shape))
    else:
        image_plot = mul_poly_shape
    fig, axs = plt.subplots()
    axs.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
    for geom in image_plot.geoms:
        xs, ys = geom.exterior.xy
        axs.fill(xs, ys, alpha=0.5, fc='r', ec='none')
    #plt.show()


csv_file_experiment = '/home/salman/Downloads/data/spacenet6/LGBM_CSVs/exp_0009_0_2.csv'
csv_file_gts = '/home/salman/Downloads/data/spacenet6/val_polygons/ground_truths.csv'


col1 = ["ImageId", "PolygonWKT_Pix","BuildingId"]
exp_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file_experiment, usecols=col1)


col2 = ["ImageId","PolygonWKT_Pix","TileBuildingId"]
gts_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file_gts, usecols=col2)
unique_gts_imageIDs = pd.unique(gts_data[['ImageId']].values.ravel())
#print("unique_gts_imageIDs: ",unique_gts_imageIDs)
count = 0
for i in unique_gts_imageIDs:
    count =  count + 1
print("count", count)

gts_inner_loop_count = 0
results1 = pd.read_csv(csv_file_gts)
gts_inner_loop_count = len(results1)
gts_inner_loop_count =  gts_inner_loop_count + 1

inner_loop_count = 0
results = pd.read_csv(csv_file_experiment)
inner_loop_count = len(results)
inner_loop_count =  inner_loop_count + 1
average_accuracy = 0.0
average_accuracy_sum = 0.0
wl = 0
match_count = 0
while wl < count:
    print("Unique Image ID: ",unique_gts_imageIDs[wl])
    print("outer loop: ",wl)
    gts_tile = []
    exp_tile = []
    k = 0
    while k <= gts_inner_loop_count:
        #print("unique_gts_imageIDs['ImageId'].get(wl) : ", unique_gts_imageIDs[wl])
        unique_Image_ID = unique_gts_imageIDs[wl]
        gts_data_Image_ID = gts_data['ImageId'].get(k)
        #print("gts_data['ImageId'].get(wl) : ", gts_data['ImageId'].get(wl))
        if unique_Image_ID == gts_data_Image_ID:
            #print("Matched")
            print("gts_data_Image_ID: ", gts_data_Image_ID)
            print("gts_data_Building_ID: ", gts_data['TileBuildingId'].get(k))
            match_count = match_count + 1
            #print("Match Count: ", match_count)
            PolygonWKT_Pix = str(gts_data['PolygonWKT_Pix'].get(k))
            #print("gts_PolygonWKT_Pix: ",PolygonWKT_Pix)
            if PolygonWKT_Pix != None and PolygonWKT_Pix != "":
                gts_tile.append(PolygonWKT_Pix)
            #gts_tile = gts_tile.append(f"{PolygonWKT_Pix}")
        k  = k + 1
    gts_img = MultiPolygon(map(wkt.loads, gts_tile))
    print ("gts_img: ",gts_img)

    t = 0
    while t <= inner_loop_count:
        #print("unique_gts_imageIDs['ImageId'].get(wl) : ", unique_gts_imageIDs[wl])
        unique_Image_ID = unique_gts_imageIDs[wl]
        exp_data_Image_ID = exp_data['ImageId'].get(t)

        #print("gts_data['ImageId'].get(wl) : ", gts_data['ImageId'].get(wl))
        if unique_Image_ID == exp_data_Image_ID:
            #print("unique_Image_ID: ", unique_Image_ID)
            print("exp_data_Image_ID: ", exp_data_Image_ID)
            print("exp_data_Building_ID: ",exp_data['BuildingId'].get(t))
            #print("Matched")
            match_count = match_count + 1
            #print("Match Count: ", match_count)
            exp_PolygonWKT_Pix = str(exp_data['PolygonWKT_Pix'].get(t))
            #print("\nexp_PolygonWKT_Pix: ",exp_PolygonWKT_Pix)
            #if exp_PolygonWKT_Pix == 'POLYGON EMPTY':
            #    exp_PolygonWKT_Pix = 0
            #    exp_PolygonWKT_Pix = str(exp_PolygonWKT_Pix)
            if exp_PolygonWKT_Pix != None and exp_PolygonWKT_Pix != "":
                exp_tile.append(exp_PolygonWKT_Pix)
            #gts_tile = gts_tile.append(f"{PolygonWKT_Pix}")
        t  = t + 1
    #print("gts_tile: ",gts_tile)
    #print("exp_tile: ",exp_tile)
    exp_img = MultiPolygon(map(wkt.loads, exp_tile))
    print("exp_img: ",exp_img)


    intersection = gts_img.intersection(exp_img)
    union = gts_img.union(exp_img)

    #print("intersection: ", intersection)
    #print("union: ", union)

    #polt_image(gts_tile)
    #polt_image(exp_tile)
    #polt_image(intersection)
    #polt_image(union)
    print(intersection.area)
    if intersection.area == 0.0 and union.area == 0.0:
            image_accuracy = 0.0
    else:
        image_accuracy = intersection.area / union.area
    print("\nimage_accuracy: " , image_accuracy)
    average_accuracy_sum = average_accuracy_sum + image_accuracy
    print("average_accuracy_sum", average_accuracy_sum)
    wl = wl + 1



average_accuracy = average_accuracy_sum / count
print("average_accuracy: ", average_accuracy)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the IOU score as a loss function, I recommend rasterizing each map. Create a 2D pixel map (image) with the value 1 everywhere a building is predicted, and 0 everywhere else. Repeat for the ground truth. You can easily get the intersection area and individual areas by summing over these maps, or by first doing a bitwise and operation and then summing over the pixel maps.

Note that the precision of this method of IOU calculation is dependent on the granularity of your raster map.

Comment: kindly share any helping code.

Comment: Generally to get quality help on SO you need to post code (here, not a link) that would reasonably be required for someone to answer the question. So you should probably post code at least showing how your ground truth and predictions are stored, computed, etc. and anything else someone would need to provide a meaningful code-based answer

Comment: I have shared the ground truths and predictions for all images and attached files with external sharing sites because those cannot be attached here. These files have all the information required(ImageID, Buildings Polygons WKT Dimensions etc).

Comment: On SO, external links = bad and unlikely to get you an answer in almost all cases, sorry